# removing the <br/> tag above call for price button using zen cart

Tags: zen-cart

In zen cart ,i added prices for some products ,they are displayed well.the problem is i dont give the prices for some products instead of giving prices,i set the call for price option.after setting that button is coming,but its not viewed properly.
when i check the inspect element code i see the 
 tag in price class .how can i delete this br tag, and which file i have to delete .i saw the inspect element code like this ..

```
    <div class="price">
    <strong><br><img src="includes/templates/template_default/images/call_for_prices.jpg" alt="Call for Price" title=" Call for Price " width="110" height="27"></strong>
    </div>
```

i want to delete this br tag before img ,in which file i have to deletet this tag.help me any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit your

> includes/functions/functions_prices.php

Find this piece of code (around line 277)

`// If Call for Price, Show it
    if ($product_check->fields['product_is_call']) {
      if (PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_IMAGE_ON=='0') {
        $call_tag = '<br />' . PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_FOR_PRICE_TEXT;
      } else {
        $call_tag = '<br />' . zen_image(DIR_WS_TEMPLATE_IMAGES . OTHER_IMAGE_CALL_FOR_PRICE, PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_FOR_PRICE_TEXT);
      }
    }`

and remove the br tags so the code looks like this:

```
// If Call for Price, Show it
if ($product_check->fields['product_is_call']) {
  if (PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_IMAGE_ON=='0') {
    $call_tag = PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_FOR_PRICE_TEXT;
  } else {
    $call_tag = zen_image(DIR_WS_TEMPLATE_IMAGES . OTHER_IMAGE_CALL_FOR_PRICE, PRODUCTS_PRICE_IS_CALL_FOR_PRICE_TEXT);
  }
}
```